# jQueryのクリックメソッドを、クリックせずに呼び出したい

Tags: jquery

下記のようなコードがあるのですが、

```
$('.hoge').on('click',function (e){
  //中略
});
```

---

クリックせずに、クリックしたものとして呼び出すには、どう書けば良いですか？
・下記では駄目ですか？

```
$('.hoge').trigger('click');
```

---

**具体例を追記しました**
・下記でボタンクリックせずに、"hoge clicked!"とコンソールログ表示させるにはどう書けば良いですか？

```
<button class="hoge">hoge</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('.hoge').on('click',function (e){
    console.log("hoge clicked!");
  });
  // .hogeのクリックイベントを実行する。
  $('.hoge').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

Comment: 具体例をスペユニットで実行すると、hoge clicked!がconsoleにでますけど。。なにかエラーがありますか？

Comment: 勘違いしていました。改めて確認したら、コンソール表示確認できました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 下記では駄目ですか？
>   $('.hoge').trigger('click');

駄目ではありません。`trigger`で良いです。

以下に、`trigger`の利用例を記載します。

```js
$(function() {
  $('.hoge').on('click',function (e){
    console.log("hoge clicked!");
  });
  
  $('.moge').on('click',function (e){
    console.log("moge clicked!");
    // .hogeのクリックイベントを実行する。
    $('.hoge').trigger('click');
  });
  
  // 初回に.hogeのクリックイベントを実行する。
  $('.hoge').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="hoge">hoge</button>
<button class="moge">moge</button>
```

Comment: $('.hoge').trigger('click');を、$('.moge').on('click',function (e){}の中に書いているのはなぜですか？ クリックイベントは、クリックしないと発火できない？？ 疑問点を本文に追記しました

Comment: @re9 さん、クリックしなくても発火できます。サンプルを修正しましたので確認してください。

Comment: 確認出来ました。ありがとうございます